# Is Freeman — Tukey's transformation the most powerful for percentages?

Tags: data-transformation, percentage

I've described a typical design for my experiments [in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11887/what-experimental-design-is-this). Well, 1-way RM ANOVA assumes a Gaussian distributed vector.
I try $y=\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}$. But for some data it works, for some doesn't... So the next step is to find the most powerful/general statistics. [Freeman — Tukey's transformation](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-21/issue-4/Transformations-Related-to-the-Angular-and-the-Square-Root/10.1214/aoms/1177729756.full) with $y=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}$ is the most powerful and seems to be appropriate in almost all my cases but again it doesn't give normal data sometimes.
What should I do this case? [Box — Cox transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/what-other-normalizing-transformations-are-commonly-used-beyond-the-common-ones)?
Is it OK to transform data using different statistics within a paper?

Comment: Do you mean the arcsin(square root(x))?  If not, that could be why it didn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "But for some data it doesn't work"? In what sense did that transformation not work? Also, what do you mean by "the most powerful statistics"? Powerful in what sense?

Comment: @Wolfgang: thanks for your questions. Let say I have 2 cell types. For cell.type_1 the FT works i.e. it transforms to normality, for the other cell type it doesn't. I meant "powerful" as synonym for "powerful" (i.e. capable to transform "any" to normality) (Correct me please if I'm wrong?). [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/if-i-count-cells-should-i-consider-them-as-poisson-distributed) I was recommended to use $\beta$ distribution but I can't understand what do I have to do in this case... :(

Comment: Okay - that clarifies things a bit. But more questions: How are you determining whether a particular set of data are normally distributed? Also, since you mention the 1-way RM ANOVA: Are you looking at the data of each individual person or are you looking at the data for each separate condition/time-point? Finally, according to the other question you linked to, are you looking again at percentages?

Comment: @Wolfgang: thanks for the reply. (1) As my data are related (= dependent) I check all data set for *normality* using $Shapiro$ — $Wilk's$ $W$ statistic (unfortunately I don't understand this but I was told to do in this way). (2) As far as I understood your question: well, *"for each separate conditions"* probably. Why do I use 1 donor's cells per 5 conditions instead of 5 donor's cells per 1 condition each? Just to have a within subject control, i.e. to be ensure to have difference (if any) caused by my substances, not between individuals. (3) Yes, my data presented are in *percentages*.

Comment: You say "data sets". So let me see if I understand you correctly. In each data set, you have $n$ individuals, each measured across $p$ different conditions (for a total of $n \times p$ data points). Then you take all of those data points and test them for normality in each data set. And you find that in some data sets, the test is significant and in others it is not. Is that correct? Or are you getting the test from normality as part of the output that you get when running one-way repeated-measures ANOVAs in each data set?

Comment: @Wolfgang: to your *"Is that correct?"* the answer is *"exactly"*. But unfortunately I can't understand the 2nd part of your post. Do you want to know the sequence of my steps? Well, it is from Normality to 1-way RM ANOVA. Excuse me for my misinterpretation and thank you for the leading questions.

Comment: I see. What you really should be checking is the normality of the residuals after fitting the model, not the normality of the dependent variable itself. See, for example [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7825/1934), which is quite related.